# WCF service SecurityNegotiationException

Tags: wcf, security, exception, service

I am running a simple service on my server with WCF; the service is hosted in WebDev.WebServer.exe (local).

When I call the Service local I get the following exception:

> Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: Secure channel cannot be opened because security negotiation with the remote endpoint has failed. This may be due to absent or incorrectly specified EndpointIdentity in the EndpointAddress used to create the channel.
>   Please verify the EndpointIdentity specified or implied by the EndpointAddress correctly identifies the remote endpoint.  ---> System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The message with Action 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/Issue' cannot be
>   processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of
>   either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver. Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).

Here are my two app.config files from the client and the server. I made the app.config from the client with the svcutil-Tool so it should be right:

#### Client

```
<client>
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:1634/UsuarioContexto.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IUsuarioContexto"

        contract="CarWin.ServiceContracts.Interfaces.IUsuarioContexto" name="LOCAL_WSHttpBinding_IUsuarioContexto">

        <identity><dns value="localhost" /></identity>

    </endpoint>

</client>

<binding name="WSHttpBinding_IUsuarioContexto" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">

    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />

    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false" />

    <security mode="Message">

        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />

        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="true" />

    </security>

</binding>
```

#### Server

```
<services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="UsuarioContextoBehavior" name="UserContext.Host.UsuarioContexto">

        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingNamespace="http://CarWin" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding_IUsuarioContexto"

                  contract="CarWin.ServiceContracts.Interfaces.IUsuarioContexto">

            <identity>

                <dns value="localhost" />

            </identity>

        </endpoint>

        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />

    </service>

</services>


<bindings>

    <wsHttpBinding>

        <binding name="wsHttpBinding_IUsuarioContexto" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">

            <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" />

            <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false" />

            <security mode="None">

                <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />

                <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" establishSecurityContext="true" />

            </security>

        </binding>

    </wsHttpBinding>

</bindings>

<behaviors>

    <serviceBehaviors>

        <behavior name="UsuarioContextoBehavior">

            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />

            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />

        </behavior>

    </serviceBehaviors>

</behaviors>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem was in server, I put mode="Message" and works well. thanks.

```
<security mode="None">  

<transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />  

<message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" establishSecurityContext="true" />  

</security>
```

Comment: This helped, thanks! I've been stuck on this for a few hours now, unable to determine why SecurityNegotiationException kept being thrown on my web app when *every* other method of connecting worked flawlessly.

Comment: What if I WANT security level NONE? How can I fix this on the caller side?

Answer (score 4):

WCF is very powerful, but can be a config nightmare.  Here are some potential leads:

- Turn on the WCF trace logs, rerun your scenario and then check the logs with SvcTraceViewer.exe
- Figure out how far the messaging gets...

  - i.e. does the client form the request and send it to the server who rejects it (i.e. in the lower WCF layers before your own service code is hit);
  - or does the request get stopped in its tracks before that.. the client never even sending the request
- http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/Issue is a WS-Trust token-related message, so there'll be something going on with authentication

  - the error's implying that there's a config mismatch, but using SvcUtil should have them lined up like you said
- The client binding has the server at "http://localhost:1634/UsuarioContexto.svc"

  - I don't see that port specified in the service config...  is the service listening on that port?
  - if you open a browser and aim it at that URL, do you get a default service page?

Comment: The problem was in: <security mode="None"> in server config. Thanks.